# xcode updated from 14.2 to 14.3 and error after update "Undefined symbol: _swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-firebase

[image]

Today Xcode version was updated from 14.2 to 14.3 and this error started popping up.
can anyone have solution of this error.

Comment: fix : I downgraded back to XCode 14.2 for now, and it all worked.